# position_dodge() does not dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to dodge the position of my bars, but it simply does not do it and I honestly have no clue why.

This is my code:

```
 y = c(10.3,12.3,2.3,4.5,6,7.8)
 df <- data.frame(
   video = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
   ERDERS = y,
   group = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)))

     p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=factor(group), y= ERDERS, x= video))
   p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(color = "gray60", stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +               
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3, 21), name = "Activity[%]")+                                  # Y-Axis scaling + title
   scale_x_discrete(name = "VIDEO", labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))+
   theme_bw()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You have six data points and six bars, what exactly should be dodged?

Comment: Always two of them should be dodged, i.e. according to the factor group.

Comment: Well, there should be a way to still group videos 1/2 (group 1), 3/4 (group 2) and videos 5/6 (group 3). If I have 6 different videos I would like to plot the values of, I need six different x values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still a bit confused, but perhaps you were looking for this?:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(y = ERDERS, x = group, fill = video))
p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(color = "gray60", stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3, 21), name = "Activity[%]") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "GROUP", labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")) +
  theme_bw()
```

This is what your example code produces:

[image: Yours]

This is what my suggestion produces. The videos are now grouped.

[image: Mine]

You can also use facets:

```
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(y = ERDERS, x = video)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = 'free_x')
p3 <- p3 + geom_bar(color = "gray60", stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3, 21), name = "Activity[%]") + theme_bw() + 
  ggtitle('Groups')
```

[image: facets]

Comment: Hmm, but the result here is not different from the result I got with the sample code, is it?

Comment: They sure look different to me. Added the plots.

Comment: Ah, my mistake! Something broke, had to restart R and now it is working! That is what I was looking for, although I had hoped there was a solution to keep the old x-axis...thanks!

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot! :) Actually, that was not exactly what I had been looking for, but looks a lot better!